# Jquery scroll function for nested <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a nav that scrolls to a corresponding `<div>` for my site. The corresponding `divs` are nested inside another `div` with a `max-height` and scrollbar. That's when my jquery tends to fail me.

He's a fiddle from another question that I related to my problem: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pyL62v58/)

Notice when you click the button, it doesn't scroll to the correct `div`, and it scrolls to an awkward position when clicked again.

How do I get it to scroll to the correct div and not strangely scroll back when it is clicked again? Thanks!

Comment: did one of Our solutions helped you or have you found a better one?  Please share or vote. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`$(".third").offset().top)` alternates coordinates between 1108 and 0 when clicked. These are the correct positions of `.third` before each click. You have to take into account the current scroll position and the position of the `.first` div.

Replace the scrollTop line of code with the following:

```
scrollTop: $(".third").position().top - $('div.nest').position().top + $('div.nest').scrollTop()},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyL62v58/3/

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The Code works, it seems to be a padding/margin issue.

Just add this line in the css, and it should work:

```
* {paddin:0;margin:0}
/*  tested on Chrome 39+ on Win7 */
```

here the Updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyL62v58/1/)**

Why it jumps up again, is hopefully clear. Documentation to the "offset" function can be found here: [jQuery-Doc](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)